# Facing issues while executing commands when installing Experience Optimization on Fredhopper Environment

Tags: web8, fredhopper, experience-optimization

Following the [SDL Web Experience Optimization 8 documentation, installing Fredhopper](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web%20Experience%20Optimization-v2/GUID-0A26A886-0DC2-4889-A939-CB07E8C5BA43#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D.xml&docid=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D), while executing:

- Step 5 [Open a command prompt and run the following command in the target folder to start the deployment agent: `bin\deployment-agent`]

  - Response : No response received.
- Step 6 [Open up another command prompt and run the following command to create your instances as specified in the topology file (in this case, ExperienceOptimization and ExperienceOptimizationLive): `bin\setup-cluster`]

  - Response : Finished with Errors.

Comment: Your *Response : Finished with Errors* is rather vague, can you edit your question and give some details about what errors you are exactly getting?

Comment: I think that's the actual message he's receiving

Comment: You need to look in the Fredhopper logs to find the actual errors. It might be nothing, but usually it means that something didn't work.

Comment: BartKoopman as Nuno Linhares stated "Finished with errors" is my actual response. @PeterKjaer : I have checked the logs but nothing was stated regarding the issues.

Comment: You should check all of the logs for every instance in your cluster, as well as the agent log. There will be an error in there somewhere -- otherwise you wouldn't be getting that message.

Comment: @PeterKjaer : Editing the batch file and enabling the echo mode c:\fredhopper>Set status=c:\fredhopper>goto endc:\fredhopper>Set status=c:\fredhopper>if "Windows_NT" == "Windows_NT" goto endNTc:\fredhopper>Set status=c:\fredhopper>if "" == "on" (if 0 NEQ 0 exit 0 )
c:\fredhopper>Set status=c:\fredhopper>exit /B 0c:\fredhopper>if "c:\fredhopper>exit /B 0 " == "STOPPED" goto continue
c:\fredhopper>echo kitchen already running for deployment  1>&2
kitchen already running for deployment
c:\fredhopper>exit /b 1
c:\fredhopper>if errorlevel 1 goto errorexit
c:\fredhopper>exit /b 1 "i gt d abv"

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do with that information.

Comment: After the setup-cluster script has finished you can review the log files data/log/agent.log and data/instances/deployment/log/kitchen.log.

These files should not contain any errors.

Comment: Provide the topology.txt file also mention the which fredhopper version did you install

Answer (score -1):

In the plain text file you creating you will be mentioning as defined in the sdl docs  [Installing Fredhopper](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CFD6A69A-D898-4680-AA23-C4B627BDA45D)  Step 3 given below:

## The topology file defines your indexing and live servers

## instance name | host | preset | indexer | comment

ExperienceOptimization|localhost|1|-|Indexer and Preview environment for demo setup 
 
ExperienceOptimizationLive|localhost|2|ExperienceOptimization|Live Query Server for demo setup 

**Instead try replacing the words** 
ExperienceOptimization| as indexer| and 
ExperienceOptimizationLive| as query1| 
which works fine creating the instance folder.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding this question and answer. It looks to me like you decided to name your instances differently than what the guide suggested and it didn't work because you weren't consistent in that naming (some commands still used the ones suggested in the guide)?

Answer (score -1):

for first step there will not be any response on command prompt. 
after executing step 5 navigate to any browser and try to execute url http://localhost:8177

This might take some time(5-10 min) before it actually return status on browser.

Step No 6 usual doesn't gives any error if topology file is correct. Please share your topology file. Make sure to give required permissions(r/w) to the user to make modification in file system. Give a try after making changes to permissions.

Once you are able to hit 8177 port then execute your commands to start Indexer. If everything goes fine than you will be able to access fredhopper on http://localhost:8180 if setup has been configured correctly with preset 1 and 2.

Keep you cmd windows running in background